# Drawing Social graph in matlab and tag nodes

Tags: matlab, graph

I need help about the social network graph.

1.) Can I put tags on the nodes?

2.) How can I modify the connecting lines?

The social network graph should look like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804468/drawing-a-network-of-nodes-in-circular-formation-with-links-between-nodes?lq=1).

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I put tags on the nodes?

Are you referring to the following question?
[Drawing a network of nodes in circular formation with links between nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804468/drawing-a-network-of-nodes-in-circular-formation-with-links-between-nodes)

A general method to add textual labels to a graph is to use the [`text`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html) command. Note that it requires the coordinates for each label. It's also recommended to make sure that the label doesn't overlap with the node.

The following example follows [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5804468#5806123), and simply adds a small radial offset to each coordinate before displaying the label at that position:

```
idx = 1:numel(x);
tags = cellstr(num2str(idx(:)), '%0d');       %// Generate string labels
[dx, dy] = pol2cart(theta, 0.1);              %// Small radial offset
dx = dx - 0.05 * (sign(x) < 0);
for k = idx;
    text(x(k) + dx(k), y(k) + dy(k), tags{k}) %// Add label
end
```

This is the result:

[image: result1]

> How can I modify the connecting lines?

Again, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5804468#5806123) shows you how: modify `ind1` and `ind2` accordingly to hold the pairs that you want to connect (each two corresponding elements in `ind1` and `ind2` make a pair).

For example, if you're interested only in connecting nodes (1,10), (2,16), (3,23) and (6,19), use the following values for `ind1` and `ind2`:

```
ind1 = [1 2 3 6];
ind2 = [10 16 23 19];
```

Running the code for the new connections values produces the following plot:

[image: result2]

Comment: sorry again, in ind1 = [1 2 3 6] can put words; i ask because i have a project about social graph

Comment: No, `ind1` and `ind2` are the index values of nodes. The "words" (labels) should go in the [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) `tags`. If you In my example I've put the labels "01, 02, 03 ... 30" in `tags` using a sophisticated one-liner, but this is really equivalent to writing `tags = {0, 1, 2, 3, ... 30}`. You can put any string you want in `tags`, for instance: `tags = {'first', 'second', ...}`

Comment: thank you very much... i write the code but i have a problem it says Error: File: social.m Line: 2 Column: 39
Unbalanced or unexpected parenthesis or bracket.

Comment: Sorry, there was an extra `)` in the `tags` line (I removed it). By the way, I remind you that you need to copy and run the code from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5804468#5806123) too before you run my code.

Comment: I run the code but it have problem says again:Error in social.m (line 11)
tags = cellstr(num2str(idx(:)), '%0d');       %// Generate string labels

Comment: But what does the error message say?

Comment: Error in social.m (line 11) tags = cellstr(num2str(idx(:)), '%0d');       %// Generate string labels

Comment: it don't genarate string labels and shows only nodes

Comment: No, that's not the error. You say MATLAB stops at line 11. What does it say in addition to what you already wrote?

Comment: I understand thank you very much :)... I have one more question can i put a node in center of circle?

Comment: Sure. Add point (0, 0) to the arrays `x` and `y`.

Comment: thank you very much for help.I need this for my project

Comment: sorry again x and y arrays points(0,0) i put in all code?